# how to use ipu3-cio camera in linux

Tags: drivers, thinkpad, webcam, camera, v4l

I have a Thinkpad X1 Tablet (gen 2) with a front and back integrated camera running Ubuntu 19:10. The cameras appear to be detected:

> $ v4l-info
>
> #### v4l2 device info [/dev/video0]
>
> general info
>       VIDIOC_QUERYCAP
>   driver : "ipu3-cio2"
>   card : "Intel IPU3 CIO2"
>   bus_info : "PCI:0000:00:14.3"
>   version : 5.3.18
>   capabilities : 0x84201000 [?,?,STREAMING,(null)]
>
> standards
>
> inputs
>       VIDIOC_ENUMINPUT(0)
>   index : 0
>   name : "camera"
>   type : CAMERA
>   audioset : 0
>   tuner : 0
>   std : 0x0 []
>   status : 0x0 []
>
> controls

When I start cheese I have 4 cameras labeled "ipu3-imgu". When I run guvcview I have 10 devices labeled "ipu3-imgu" which the system puts at /dev/video0-9 and four devices labeled "Intel IPU3 CIO2" which are /dev/video10-13.

But none of these work. Does anyone have a laptop with this kind of camera running Linux?

Does anyone know of a resource on debugging this kind of camera in Linux?

Answer (score 2):

The IPU3 CIO2 device is a MIPI CSI-2 receiver. It can capture video from a camera sensor without any processing. Camera sensors used with IPU3 devices are usually raw Bayer sensors, which means not only that will most applications not work with them (as they expect RGB or YUV data), but also that the image quality will be very poor without image processing algorithms running auto-exposure or auto-white balance. The good news is that work is ongoing to support devices based on the Intel IPU3 as part of the http://libcamera.org/ project.

libcamera is a relatively new userspace framework to support this kind of cameras. It requires support from kernel drivers, so the first step will be to ensure that the IPU3 CIO2 driver correctly detects the camera sensor. You can do so by checking the media pipeline with the media-ctl tool, part of v4l-utils. I recommend asking from support on the libcamera mailing list or IRC channel.

Comment: Can you post instructions on how exactly this can be resolved?